# Can I run davinci resolve without openCL capable GPU?

Tags: premiere, davinci-resolve

Hey I'm currently using my old macbook pro 13 and i just found out it doesn't have/support any openCL GPUs and therefore i can't run davinci resolve. Is there any way to go around it? If not, are there any other video editing apps that doesn't require openCL capable GPUs? premiere pro maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there’s a way round it. Premiere can operate using CPU only.